# Что значит слово "возомненье"? Что такое "скаредный скрытень"?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов

Контекст такой:

«Ты должна

заснуть, возомненья приидут иные»;

---

«Их скаредный скрытень скрадет и меня».

"Скаредный" можно не пересказывать, но зачем жадному сундуку или ухоронке живая я?

---

Мне на это ответили страшноЭ:

> Возомнения, си речь помыслы, умышления.
>
> Скаредный скрытень, си речь - тайный, хитрый, и жадный похититель
>   (прячущй похищенное)... но это исходя из моих познаний беларусскай
>   мовы.

**[Полный текст](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1429076-hozhu-po-okolicam-djuzhej-vesny-mozhno-li-najti-v-inete-ssylochku-by-a.html)** ахмадулинского стихотворения.

---

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Нашла **[ещё один текст](https://ruslib.net/read/b/1766/p/56)**, но он не разделён на четверостишия, пробую разбить, в отсутствии ошибок не уверена...

---

Хожу по околицам дюжей весны,

вкруг полой воды, и сопутствие чье-то

глаголаше: «Колицем должен еси?» —

сочти, как умеешь, я сбилась со счёта.

---

Хотелось мне моря, Батума, дождя,

кофейни и фески Омара-соседа.

Бубнило уже: «Ты должна, ты должна!» —

и двинулась я не овамо, а семо.

---

Прибой возыметь за спиной, на восток,

вершины ожегший, воззриться – могла ведь.

Всевластье трубы помавает хвостом,

предместье-прихвостье корпит, помогает.

---

Закат – и скорбит и робеет душа

пред пурпуром смрадным, прекрасно-зловещим.

Над гранью земли – ты должна, ты должна! —

на злате небес – филигрань-человечек.

---

Его пожирает отверстый вулкан,

его не спасет тихомолка оврага,

идет он – и поздно его окликать —

вдоль пламени, в челюсти антропофага.

---

Сближаются алое и фиолет.

Как стебель в средине захлопнутой книги,

меж ними расплющен его силуэт —

лишь вмятина видима в стынущем нимбе.

---

Добыча побоища и дележа —

невзрачная крапина крови и воли.

Как скушно жужжит: «Ты должна, ты должна!» —

тому ли скитальцу? Но нет его боле.

---

Я в местной луне, поначалу, своей

луны не узнала, да сжалилась лунность

и свойски зависла меж черных ветвей —

так ей приглянулась столь смелая глупость.

---

Меж тем я осталась одна, как она:

лишь нищие звери тянулись во други

да звук допекал: «Ты должна, ты должна!» —

ужель оборучью хапуги-округи?

---

Ее постояльцы забыли мотив,

родимая речь им далече латыни,

снуют, ненасытной мечтой охватив

кто – реки хмельные, кто – горы златые.

---

Не ласки и взоры, а лязг и возня.

Пришла для подачи – осталась при плаче.

Их скаредный скрытень скрадет и меня.

Незнаемый молвил: «Тем паче, тем паче».

---

Текут добры молодцы вотчины вспять.

Трущобы трещат – и пусты деревеньки.

Пошто бы им загодя джинсы не дать?

По сей промтовар все идут в делинквенты.

---

Восход малолетства задирчив и быстр:

тетрадки да прятки, а больше – рогатки.

До зверских убийств от звериных убийств

по прямопутку шагают ребятки.

---

Заради наживы решат на ножах:

не пусто ли брату остаться без брата?

Пребудут не живы – мне будет не жаль.

Истец улыбнулся: «Неправда, неправда».

---

Да ты их не видывал! Кто ты ни есть,

они в твою высь не взглянули ни разу.

И крестят детей, полагая, что крест —

условье улова и средство от сглазу.

---

До станции и до кладбища дошла,

чей вид и названье содеяны сажей.

Опять донеслось: «Ты должна, ты должна!» —

я думала, что-нибудь новое скажет.

---

Забытость надгробья нежна и прочна.

О, лакомка, сразу доставшийся раю!

«Вкушая, вкусих мало мёду, – прочла,

уже не прочесть: – и се аз умираю».

---

Заведомый ангел, жилец неземной,

как прочие все оснащенный скелетом.

«Ночной – на дневной, а шестой – на седьмой!» —

вдруг рявкнул вблизи станционный селектор.

---

Я стала любить эти вскрики ничьи,

пророчества малых событий и ругань.

Утешно мне их соучастье в ночи,

когда сортируют иль так, озоруют.

---

Гигант-репетир ударяет впотьмах,

железо наслав на другое железо:

вагону, под горку, препона – «башмак» —

и сыплется снег с потрясенного леса.

---

Твердящий темно: «Ты должна, ты должна!» —

учись направлять, чтобы слышащий понял,

и некий ночной, грохоча и дрожа,

воспомнил свой долг и веленье исполнил.

---

Незрячая ощупь ума не точна:

лелея во мгле коридора-ущелья,

не дали дитяти дьячка для тычка,

для лестовицей ременной наущенья.

---

Откройся: кто ты? Ослабел и уснул

злохмурый, как мурин, посёлок немытый.

Суфлёр в занебесном укрытье шепнул:

«Ты знаешь его, он – неправедный мытарь.

---

Призвал он кого́ждо из должников,

и мало взыскал, и хвалим был от Бога».

Но, буде ты – тот, почему не таков

и не отпустишь от мзды и побора?

---

Окраина эта тошна и душна! —

Брезгливо изрёк сортировочный рупор:

«Зла суща – ступай, ибо ты не должна

ни нам, ни местам нашим гиблым и грубым.

---

Таков уж твой сорт». – И подавленный всхлип

превысил слова про пути и про рейсы.

Потом я узнала: там сцепщик погиб.

Сам голову положил он на рельсы.

---

Не он ли вчера, напоследок дыша,

вдоль неба спешил из огня да в полымя?

И слабый пунктир – ты должна, ты должна! —

насквозь пролегал между нами двоими.

---

Хожу к тете Тасе, сижу и гляжу

на розан бумажный в зеленом вазоне.

Всю ночь потолок над глазами держу,

понять не умею и каюсь во злобе.

---

Иду в Афанасово крепким ледком,

по талой воде возвращаюсь оттуда.

И по пути, усмехнувшись тайком,

куплю мандариновый джем из Батума.

---

Покинувший – снова пришел: «Ты должна

заснуть, возомненья приидут иные».

Заснежило, и снизошла тишина,

и молвлю во сне: отпущаеши ныне…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ахмадулина использует архаизмы в разных функциях, иногда даже изобретает архаические окказионализмы. Здесь похоже на возомнение = воображение, вернее, воображаемый образ, видение.

Др.-р.-мнить –обдумывать, взвешивать, в праслав. – мыслить, помнить.

Возомнить - устаревшее значение "помыслить, счесть". Вообще,"мнение" - заимств. из старослав., в котором оно является калькой с греч. "мнение, предположение", а "возо" - отсылка к высокому стилю, к чему-то старославянскому.

В 11 веке появилось страдат. причастие Мнимый (образованное как "любимый") -воображаемый, мыслимый, отсюда - не существующий в действительности.Вот к этому значению корня и восходит существительное Ахмадулиной - возомнение - воображение.

Скаредный - устар. скверный, мерзкий, гнусный  ◆ — Ему за скаредные дела головку перед сенатом срубили. П. И. Мельников-Печерский, «Бабушкины россказни».

Скрытень - понятно кто, какой-нибудь вурдалак.

Скаредный скрытень - мерзкий монстр, вурдалак. В страшных снах всегда кого-нибудь утаскивает в царство смерти.

Comment: "У фасадной стены в одном простенке стоял цветок, а в другом висело зеркало, и стоял на полу сундук–скрытня, окованный железом". А, я была права! "СКРЫТЕНЬ, тня, м. Большой берестяной или лубяной сосуд с крышкой для хранения сыпучих веществ". СЛОВАРЬ ВОЛОГОДСКИХ ГОВОРОВ. "Скаредный — скупердяйский, прижимистый, жлобский, сквалыжный, скуповатый, жмотский, скалдырный, скалдырнический".  Жмотский сундучок-ухоронок получается по контексту и вне.

Answer (score 2):

Для расшифровки поэтических вольностей изменим порядок слов на прозаический:

*Скаредный скрытень иных возомнений, грядущих в твоём сне,  скрадёт и меня тоже.*

Иными словами, некий обитатель мира сна (условный Морфей) похищает и прячет людские "возомнения"; заодно он похитит и упрячет мысли обо "мне".

**Возомнение** - отглагольное существительное от **возомнить** (= составить себе ложное представление - например, о себе или о своих возможностях).

Соответственно, текст выглядит как рекомендация поспать и этим отвлечься от навязчивых представлений, неосуществимых надежд (возомнений), включая мысли о лирическом герое (их "сокрадут"), на иные, тоже ложные видения, которые придут в форме снов.

Comment: Скаредный скрытень принадлежит "им", обитателям оборучья-округи, и если их "восход малолетства" (детки) "пребудут не живы" - мне будет не жаль! Торг у "меня" идёт с небесным суфлером и неправедным мытарем, но порой отвечает, как в фильме ужасов, станционный селектор. Есть они и я, и я им почему-то постоянно должна. Грядущий сон снимет эти "возомненья" (заменив иными), чёртово Иваново отпустит меня. "Я" пришла, чтобы подать, а меня тут вот-вот съедят - скрытень скрадёт и меня... (Так я, Г. А., пробираюсь через текст.)

Comment: *Для расшифровки поэтических вольностей* я сейчас попробую пересказать каждую строфу, что в комменте сделать невозможно, *изменив порядок слов на прозаический*.

Comment: Если "скрытень" орудует в потустороннем мире, то пожелание "заснуть" - кому и от кого? Сортировочный рупор в чистилище установлен?

Comment: Говорящих (порой через селектор) двое - тот, кто назван "суфлёром", и "неправедный мытарь". Их речь закавычена. "Моя" (Изабеллина) - нет. Дело происходит в этом мире, в Иванове, на станции, в марте 1986-го, конкретнее некуда. Пожелание заснуть - с небес на землю, исстрадавшейся Белке.

Answer (score 1):

> Возомнения, си речь помыслы, умышления.
>
> Скаредный скрытень, си речь - тайный, хитрый, и жадный похититель
>   (прячущй похищенное)... но это исходя из моих познаний беларусскай
>   мовы.

Вам правильно ответили, только белорусский здесь совершенно ни при чем. 
Возомнение, скрытень - Это не похоже на архаизмы. Скорее авторский новодел, первое - отвлеченное существительное от глагола "возомнить". 
Скрытень - тот кто прячется, скрывается. Это встречается, про "сундук" не скажу. Интересно, что этим словом переводчики Гарри Поттера перевели английское Hidebehind, коим в оригинале назван тайный дух, фантом (кажется они делились еще на морских и лесных). Ахмадуллина о том знать не могла, но совпадение очевидное.

Comment: Я было повелся на вашу уверенность, что "новодел", но ведь там по всему тексту бесспорные архаизмы. Вряд ли в двух отдельных случаях что-то другое, самодельное. А значения - да, согласен.

Comment: @Мимоходов   Согласен отчасти, но уж очень странные это старославянизмы.